# ¿Cómo puedo iterar diferentes variables en un ciclo for y almacenar esa información en una lista?

Tags: c++

Quisiera saber cómo puedo iterar en un solo ciclo `for` diferentes variables que se escriben desde la consola:
Por ejemplo:

```
cout << "  Ingrese el valor de la su columna: "; cin >> c;
cout << "  Ingrese el valor de la trabe: "; cin >> t;
cout << "  Ingrese el valor de la losa: "; cin >> l;
```

Todas esas variables me gustaría hacerlo en un solo ciclo for para optimizar el código y evitar la redundancia. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo y al mismo tiempo los valores se almacenen en algún lugar?
Mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "conio.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");
    int c, t, l;

    cout << "  Ingrese el valor de la su columna: "; cin >> c;
    cout << "  Ingrese el valor de la trabe: "; cin >> t;
    cout << "  Ingrese el valor de la losa: "; cin >> l;
}
```

Agradezco mucho su apoyo. Saludos!

Comment: Si haces un bucle, la variable tiene que ser siempre la misma, con lo que tendría que ser un array de enteros, guardando en cada posición un entero. Pero el mensaje que muestras en cada iteración es distinto, porque pides cosas distintas, así que no lo veo. No veo que ahorres nada haciendo un bucle ni optimizas nada.

Comment: La redundancia es relativa. Si representan cosas diferentes tiene sentido que se mantengan separadas. Recuerdo un caso en el que por evitar redundancia a alguien se le ocurrió que los artículos de los albaranes que se generaban en una tienda tuviesen el id del artículo original ... luego pasó que al cambiar el precio de los artículos tambien variaba el valor de los albaranes ... un follón. Lo dicho, si son cosas diferentes no intentes optimizar

Comment: Si te recomiendo, en cambio, usar nombres de variables más representativos. `t` no significa absolutamente nada. Cuando tengas una veintena de variables y todas con esta pinta verás que el código es inmanejable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me di cuenta que se puede crear el vector de nombres utilizando la función `push_back()` en un bucle `for`, por ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> variables(3); // Creamos un vector con tres variables
    std::vector<std::string> nombres; // Creamos un vector vacío para almacenar los nombres

    // Agregamos los nombres de las variables al vector 'nombres'
    nombres.push_back("su columna");
    nombres.push_back("trabe");
    nombres.push_back("losa");

    for (int i = 0; i < variables.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "Ingrese el valor de " << nombres[i] << ": ";
        std::cin >> variables[i];
    }

    // Imprimimos los valores ingresados
    for (int i = 0; i < variables.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "El valor de " << nombres[i] << " es " << variables[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Se crea un vector vacío nombres y se agrega los nombres de las variables al vector utilizando la función `push_back()` en un bucle `for`. Luego, se utiliza el vector nombres para mostrar los nombres de las variables en la entrada de datos y en la impresión de resultados.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que hagas un array asociativo pasándole las 3 variables. Pero creo que no es posible en c++. De todos modos podrías realizarlo utilizando un array tridimencional pero lo tendrias que recorrer con un for dentro de otro for dentro de otro.

Algo asi:

```
int i;
int Matriz[c][t][l];

for(i=0; i<c;i++){

  for(i=0; i<t;i++){
  
      for(i=0; i<l;i++){
       
      }
   }
}
```

Espero que sea lo que estabas buscando y que te sirva, aunque no es un solo for, lo estarias iterando una vez.

Comment: Muchas gracias, creí que era posible realizar esto en c++ como se optimiza en python